# Каталог "Загрузки" постоянно создается сам

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте.
Пользуюсь Ubuntu 16.04 LTS с английской локализацией. Обратил внимание, что в домашнем каталоге стал появляться пустой каталог с русским именем "*Загрузки*". Создается от моего имени, так как все права на нем мои. Если его удалить, то через какое-то время он снова появляется.  Приложения, которыми пользуюсь: Atom, Firefox, Thunderbird, Transmission, rtorrent, VLC, но все, которые что-то качают из интрента, настроены на "*Download*".
Есть ли возможность узнать кто создает этот странный каталог и как-то от этого избавиться? Может на практике он и не мешает работе, но раздражает очень сильно. Спасибо.

```
$ tail -n 100 ~/.config/user-dirs.* /etc/xdg/user-dirs.*==> /home/lebvlad/.config/user-dirs.dirs <==
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

==> /home/lebvlad/.config/user-dirs.locale <==
en_US
==> /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf <==
# This controls the behaviour of xdg-user-dirs-update which is run on user login
# You can also have per-user config in ~/.config/user-dirs.conf, or specify
# the XDG_CONFIG_HOME and/or XDG_CONFIG_DIRS to override this
#

enabled=True

# This sets the filename encoding to use. You can specify an explicit
# encoding, or "locale" which means the encoding of the users locale
# will be used
filename_encoding=UTF-8

==> /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults <==
# Default settings for user directories
#
# The values are relative pathnames from the home directory and
# will be translated on a per-path-element basis into the users locale
DESKTOP=Desktop
DOWNLOAD=Downloads
TEMPLATES=Templates
PUBLICSHARE=Public
DOCUMENTS=Documents
MUSIC=Music
PICTURES=Pictures
VIDEOS=Videos
# Another alternative is:
#MUSIC=Documents/Music
#PICTURES=Documents/Pictures
#VIDEOS=Documents/Videos
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xdg-user-dir

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ tail -n 100 ~/.config/user-dirs.* /etc/xdg/user-dirs.*`

Comment: вообще создаёт каталог программа *xdg-user-dirs-update* или какой-то её аналог, запускаемый при старте x-сессии. но руководствоваться эти программы должны содержимым файлов, про которые речь в предыдущем моём комментарии.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил. P.S. Простите за долгий ответ - пропадал интернет.

Comment: судя по приложенной информации, появление каталога `~/загрузки` вряд ли стоит ожидать от программы *xdg-user-dirs-update*. но на всякий случай уточните: каталог появляется **только сразу** после старта x-сессии, или в произвольные моменты времени? если в произвольные, то источник, вероятно, — какая-нибудь работающая/запускаемая программа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сразу после старта иксов. Сейчас ради эксперимента сделал интерфейс русским - все нормально, никаких посторонних каталогов (каталог "Загруки" со стрелкой на иконке). Вернул английский и опять этот каталог "Загрузки" появляется (папка со стрелкой стоит на "Downloads", а "Загрузки" - с обычной иконкой папки без опознавательных знаков). У меня такое ощущение, что это началось после моего перехода с Transmisson на rtorrent, но логики в этом не вижу, ибо rtorrent работает с отдельным винчестером, а в ~/ хранит только свой файл настроек и сессию.

Comment: *сделал интерфейс русским* — 1. как именно? 2. что выдаёт команда `$ pgrep -u $USER | while read n; do cat /proc/$n/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0n1 echo | grep LANGUAGE; done | sort -u` в том и другом варианте?